# How do I send keystrokes to a specific app?

Tags: compiz, shortcut-keys, usability

I'd like to be able to bind a global keystroke send a sequence of keystrokes to a specific app.

Specifically: I'm using the Last.fm client, and I'd like to be able to start/stop music with a global keybinding.

Is there an app that does this? I'm using compiz, if that helps.

**Update:**

I ended up having to write a bash script. Here's the final product:
    #!/bin/sh

```
for x in `xdotool search --class last.fm`
do
    if ( xprop -id $x WM_WINDOW_ROLE | grep menuControls );
    then
            xdotool type --window $x Ctrl-m
            break
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `xdotool` that provide a `--windows` parameter to select the destination window and a `search` command to look for a window by title, name or other.